# Why did Shannen Doherty and Julian McMahon not appear in the final episode of "Charmed"?

Tags: charmed

There's no in-universe explanation as to why Shannen Doherty (Prue) and Julian McMahon (Cole) were absent from the final episode of the final season of "Charmed", while just about every other significant character from throughout the show's run was in it. Out of universe, were they just busy on other things, did they turn it down, or were they not asked?

Comment: According to the wiki, Shannon Doherty wasn't asked back for a few reasons; she was disliked by the cast and crew, she would have been very expensive and her return would have dominated the episode

Comment: To expand on what @Valorum stated, it was well known that Shannon and Alyssa didn't get along very well. I wouldn't be surprised if she wasn't asked back because of the enmity between them.

Comment: Shannon Doherty has been famously hard to work with since as far back as Little House on the Prairie.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Gosh! I'd heard that Shannen Doherty and Alyssa Milano didn't get on, but I didn't realise they'd become enemies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Shannen Doherty

Shannen Doherty states unequivocally that she ***was*** in negotiation to return for the season finale, but that she simply didn't like the way that her character would be portrayed and turned down the role.

The Charmed Wiki suggests that there were other issues, notably the cost of her paycheque, the fact that she [famously didn't get on with her co-stars](http://www.usmagazine.com/celebrity-news/news/alyssa-milano-working-with-shannen-doherty-holly-marie-combs-on-charmed-was-like-high-school-2013117) and the simple fact that her return would have completely overshadowed the finale, turning it into the "**Pru returns**" show.

---

### Julian McMahon

The show struggled to find the funding to bring back McMahon, especially given his recent success as Victor von Doom in the runaway Hollywood blockbuster 'Fantastic Four'.

> **TVGuide.com:** *With that said, what's coming up during the back half of the season? Any returns for Cole or Prue?*
>
> **Kern:** [Laughs] *In my ideal world... **The huge problem I have to deal with this year is the budget cutback. I'm trying to save money
>   each episode so I can afford to bring back as many of the regular cast
>   members as possible.** Who that will be, **I don't know, but my plan is
>   to have the equivalent of a "family reunion" including as many people
>   as I can afford. I'm not going to be able to get Julian McMahon back
>   [as Cole]; I twisted his arm, and begged and bribed him to come back
>   for the 150th episode last year, which he so lovingly offered to do.**
>   But that doesn't mean I don't have flashbacks! [Laughs] I can pull
>   back the celluloid. The goal for me is to take the series out the way
>   it began. It's interesting that one of the criticisms, rightfully so,
>   is about the lack of sisterhood, but I'm building to it being all
>   about sisters. Even when we talk about Kaley Cuoco's Billie, we're
>   going to be bringing her sister, Christy, into the show [played by
>   recent Supernatural guest star Marnette Patterson], working around the
>   final ultimate battle. That seems kind of poetic because that's what
>   the series has fundamentally always been about, and that's how it will
>   end.*

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that having Shannen Dougherty back would’ve put them in the position of having to pay her a great deal of money.  This is supposedly why there were never any pictures that included her after she was fired. I noticed this in the last episode as they showed the pictures of different family members at the end of the episode when it aired the first time and wondered about it.
I apologize that I can’t document my source.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  As you acknowledge, this would be a far better answer if you could provide a source or two.